# KnockoutJS Parsley but in knockout-parsley with radio/checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, knockout.js, parsley.js

I have a problem with knockout-parsley that I can not find a solution to.

Basically I am using Parsley http://parsleyjs.org/ and Knockout-Parsley https://github.com/gdandar/Knockout-Parsley along with knockout for validation.

This seems to be working fine for most controls, but I am getting an exception from within Knockout about a binding to the checked property when the control is a radio button or checkbox.

The exception is :

```
SCRIPT5007: Object expected 
knockout-3.0.0.debug.js, line 2609 character 21
```

I have a fiddle that shows the issue although the actual exception is not displayed in the fiddle ( but you can see the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/iisfaq/N3dZr/7/

Now in the fiddle if you run it you will see that there are 3 check boxes and a text field. The text field should display the value from the observable array. And the middle checkbox should be checked.

But in the fiddle you will not see any checkbox's because of the exception.

If you comment out the line below in the fiddle it will work but not provide any validation at all.

```
ko.parsley.init('#main-form');
```

Trying to debug the exception I found that the exception occurs during the applyBindings method - ko.applyBindings(theModel);

The error message is: "Unable to process binding \"checked: function(){return abc }\"\nMessage: Object expected"

This occurs in the catch at 2609 in knockout-3.0.0.debug.js file

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It seems the Knockout-Parsley does not support Knockout 3.0. If you change the KO version to 2.3 then it works in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhFSp/

Comment: Thanks for that - I will see if I can find the issue with V3

Comment: I have found that in V3 there is no update handler for the checked binding. In parsley-knockout there is a change to the update handler, but it does not exist hence the exception. More investigating needed...